# How To Divide An Ordered List And Include Image Above Numbered Item

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to accomplish two things:

1. Include a long, numbered list that is divided up into different sections
2. Include an image within the list item and have it display above the numbered title of the list

I've tried using `<sections>` and `<lh>` (not sure if that's valid but found it elsewhere) for the headings within the list but that's not validating. Is there any way of breaking up the list into different sections with appropriate headings without creating multiple ordered lists?

And while I can include the img above the list item heading, I don't want the number to be on the image but rather on the title.

Here's the code I'm playing with that isn't validating:

```
<h1>Most Popular Pantry Items</h1>
<ol>
<h2>Fruits</h2>
<li><img src="https://example.com/image1.jpg"/><h3>Apples</h3>Text</li>
<li><img src="https://example.com/image2.jpg"/><h3>Oranges</h3>Text</li>
<h2>Vegetables</h2>
<li><img src="https://example.com/image3.jpg"/><h3>Carrots</h3>Text</li>
<li><img src="https://example.com/image4.jpg"/><h3>Beets</h3>Text</li>
</ol>
```

Ideally, this is one long numbered list but I'm not sure if that's possible. And how can I include the image as part of the ordered list item, have it appear above the text, but make sure it's the text within the h3 tag that is numbered?

Here's a very crude mockup:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Can you share a picture of how you want this to look?

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica Added to my post. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 1):

Some html semantics will not hurt;)

```css
.content {
  counter-reset: numb;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

.info {
  position: relative
}

.info p,
.info h3 {
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 0;
}

.info:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  counter-increment: numb;
  content: counter(numb)'. ';
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h1>Most Popular Pantry Items</h1>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <h2>Fruits</h2>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" />
      <div class="info">
        <h3>Apples</h3>
        <p>Text</pApples>
          </figcaption>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200/ff5722" />
      <div class="info">
        <h3>Oranges</h3>
        <p>Text</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>Vegetables</h2>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200/0000FF" />
      <div class="info">
        <h3>Carrots</h3>
        <p>Text</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200/000000" />
      <div class="info">
        <h3>Beets</h3>
        <p>Text</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ol>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I need an ordered list to generate a rich snippet on this page.

Comment: No problem, I switched to the list - see the example now.